# Trouble setting React native

Tags: facebook, macos, react-native, npm, npm-install

I am trying to set React Native in my Mac El Capitan system following the instructions provided in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#caveats
When I do

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

The output is the following one:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector:bin Hector$ npm install -g create-react-native-app
npm ERR! not a package /usr/local/bin/create-react-native-app
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/bin/create-react-native-app
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "create-react-native-app"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /var/folders/yz/8y2s_bl167xgcnyhdtf0yqs40000gn/T/npm-8989-2d1edf9b/unpack-97e54ff1/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/yz/8y2s_bl167xgcnyhdtf0yqs40000gn/T/npm-8989-2d1edf9b/unpack-97e54ff1/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/yz/8y2s_bl167xgcnyhdtf0yqs40000gn/T/npm-8989-2d1edf9b/unpack-97e54ff1/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/bin/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried everything including cleaning cache and other recommendations done in other groups but it doesn't work

Comment: have you install node before using npm command?

Comment: Yes. I have node, npm and even watchman

Comment: try this :- npm install -g npm@latest and make sure your have a package.json file.